# Can anyone tell me why this function throws up an error when called

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```html
   <html>
    
    <script>
    
    
    function isNumber(value) {
        return typeof (value) != "boolean" && !isNaN(value) && value.length > 0;
    }
    
    function minMaxTempDecimal(value, min, max, unit) {
        console.log("D function called");
        if (value.length == 0 || value == "-") return value;
        if (!isNumber(value)) return value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
    
        value = parseFloat(value);
        if (value) < min)
            return min;
        else if (value > max)
            return max;
        return value.toFixed(1);
    
    }
    </script>
    
    <tr>
            <th>Differntial</th>
            <th><input id="differentail" type="text" name="differentail" value="1" onkeyup="this.value = minMaxTempDecimal(this.value, 0.1, 5, 0)"   /></th>
          </tr>
          
    </html>
```

The function does the following

- limits the values from 0.1 to 5
- only decimal places to one point ie step size of 0.1
- doesn't allow characters

Comment: Also please note that you need to add `<!doctype html>` at the top of your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Read the error. You have an extra `)` in your JS code.

The following works:

```html
   <html>
    
    <script>
    
    
    function isNumber(value) {
        return typeof (value) != "boolean" && !isNaN(value) && value.length > 0;
    }
    
    function minMaxTempDecimal(value, min, max, unit) {
        console.log("D function called");
        if (value.length == 0 || value == "-") return value;
        if (!isNumber(value)) return value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
    
        value = parseFloat(value);
        if (value < min)
            return min;
        else if (value > max)
            return max;
        return value.toFixed(1);
    
    }
    </script>
    
    <tr>
            <th>Differntial</th>
            <th><input id="differentail" type="text" name="differentail" value="1" onkeyup="this.value = minMaxTempDecimal(this.value, 0.1, 5, 0)"   /></th>
          </tr>
          
    </html>
```